# Save state of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making a simple app.
Here are the codes:

Main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layout1"
    android:text="@string/go" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/urlField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/goButton"
    android:background="@drawable/layout1"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="textUri"
    android:hint="@string/enter_school_name"> 

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/urlField" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar" />
```

Main Java:

```
    package com.nextgenintl.plusportals;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private EditText urlEditText;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
            super.onBackPressed(); // finishes activity
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setMax(100);

        Button openUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        openUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
                String urlSchool = "https://www.plusportals.com/"+url;
                urlSchool = urlSchool.replace(" ", "");
                if (validateUrl(url)) {
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(urlSchool);

                    MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
                }
            }

            private boolean validateUrl(String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {         
            MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {
        this.progress.setProgress(progress);       
    }
}
```

So, I want to save the user input - the school name, so you don't have to type it every single time. But I can't really figure it out - can you please help me??? Thanks if you post me the full java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the following:**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("clever_title", urlEditText.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

**Then when you open your app the next time you can get:**

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 urlEditText.text(sp.getString("clever_title", null);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that - it only says that there is a duplicate method . . . Where do I exactly use it??? (Thanks for the answer, though)

Comment: The top part is placed wherever you want to save the field, so when they press a button or after they are done typing. From your code above it looks like it would be best to place it in your onclick(). The second part can go in onCreate() or where ever you initialize your EditText field. If you get a duplicate method you can simply change the name of one of the SharedPreferences or better yet reuse one.